# How to remove the border around the entire table in Material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to edit a table in Material-ui and I don't want to show it as a card. I would like to remove the border around the entire table and I couldn't find anything about removing the border on the document page. Can anyone help me with it?

Link about the component: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#other

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, Theme, createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

......

export default function CustomizedTables() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="customized table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <StyledTableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Calories</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <StyledTableRow key={row.name}>
              <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.calories}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.fat}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.protein}</StyledTableCell>
            </StyledTableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: are you trying to remove the borders on the rows or the border around the entire table?

Comment: @Hyetigran I'm trying to remove the borders around the entire table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TableContainer` is using `Paper` ( with default elevation ) as its background, which is why it is displaying like a card. Removing the `component={Paper}` part will remove those classes.

Use it like this

```
<TableContainer >
```

Comment: that's nice and simple!

Answer (score 3):

Add className to TableContainer component

```
 <TableContainer className={classes.tableContainer} component={Paper}>
```

Add custom style to useStyle hook

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650
  },
  tableContainer: {
    boxShadow: "none"
  }
});
```

My method:
In codesandbox, I opened devtools and inspected the component until I found the tag. Because it was outermost layer, it seemed likely to be the TableContainer component.

Thus if you were to want to eliminate the bottom border, find which tag it's set and overwrite those components in the useStyle hook.

Comment: Thanks man! The boxShadow is the exact properties I was looking for!